# Why don't MenuItems work with DynamicResource?

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, menuitem, dynamicresource

The main menu of my program uses a `ContextMenu` composed of `MenuItems`. During the localization of my program (using Resource Dictionaries), I set a `DynamicResource` as the `Header` of each one of my `MenuItems`. Strangely `DynamicResource` compiles, but doesn't seem to affect any change during localization (the language on the `Headers` does not change).

Example of a `MenuItem`:

```
//I'm not sure if the x:Name or the PlacementRectangle is interfering with anything...
<ContextMenu x:Name="MainContextMenu" PlacementRectangle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource open}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

What are the constraints of the `MenuItem` control? Is it supposed to work with `DynamicResource`? My overall goal is to localize these `strings`, how do I do that?

This program is in WPF. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
This is how my Resource Dictionaries are referenced in my App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="Lang.en-US.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
<Application.Resources>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
The example string in my English Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sys:String x:Key="open">Open</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Update 3:**
An example function for how I change the current Resource Dictionary to Spanish:

```
private void spanishChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
            (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("LangspES.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));

    LanguageChange.FireLanguageChanged();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at Microsoft's recommendations? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes I've seen this. If this is the only solution it looks like I might need to use another method for my menu.

Comment: How are you creating this MenuItem? It should work.

Comment: The `MenuItem` is included in the implementation of a `ContextMenu`. I will update my question

Comment: `\Resources\LocalizedResources.resx`, `Content="{x:Static res:LocalizedResources.YOURKEY}"`. That's how I do localization.

The language that's being read depends on the threads culture settings: 
// The following line provides localization for data formats
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = YOURCULTURE;

// The following line provides localization for the application's user interface
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = YOURCULTURE;

Comment: Have a read of the largest most comprehensive answer I've ever seen on SO... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648849/how-are-dynamicresources-built-and-their-use-in-contextmenus

Comment: @PaulZahra The part titled: "Dynamic ContextMenu updated through data binding" is getting close to what I need, but if I use this solution I don't know how to deal with `MenuItem` click events

Comment: Instead of binding the whole list through the context menu, why not bind menuitems individually? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013558/elementname-binding-from-menuitem-in-contextmenu

Comment: Are you saying that I should bind the `Headers` to `strings`?

Comment: @Ericafterdark What I'm saying is instead of binding the whole list with something like <Window.Resources><ContextMenu x:Key="Vegetables" ItemsSource="{Binding VegetableList}" /></Window.Resources> instead try binding the entries like <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=open}" /> <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=close}" /> etc

Answer (score 2):

Have you added LANGUAGE.xaml file to App.ResourceDictionary or control ResourceDictionary?

e.g.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="LANGUAGE1.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="LANGUAGE2.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

If not how are you referencing your resource dictionaries?

Update:

If you change

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource open}" />
```

to

```
<MenuItem Header="{StaticResource open}" />
```

Does it then work ? Or even does

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{StaticResource open}" />
```

work ?

Seemingly your xaml should work, which makes me wonder have you setup localisation correctly in your app?

For how to setup localisation in .net 4.5 see [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am referencing my dictionaries just like this

Comment: Non of those methods work... :-/ Right now I am even trying it with a `TextBlock`. I double checked and these words are definitely in my resource dictionaries. I can verify that localization is setup correctly because the rest of my program localizes fine.

Comment: hmmm... It's not something daft that 'open' is a reserved word is it? Try changing to something else just encase (worth trying).

Comment: Nope, changed it and still nothing

Comment: Put your language file (xaml) in your question, maybe it's something in there.

Comment: hmm... btw have you tried taking the extra full stop out ? i.e. Lang.en-US.xaml to Langen-US.xaml or even LangenUS.xaml as a test

Comment: Wow, this is frustrating. I removed the extra full stop in all of my dictionaries and still not working. FYI, the buttons that I use to change the language are located in the Menu that I am working with. I've also set a break point in the functions that I use to change the language and verified that the code does get run through. I've updated my question with one of those functions.

Comment: hmm... a bit stumped to be honest... at this point i would begin seperation of code to isolate the problem, beginning with just setting up a merged dictionary and reading from it to a text box, then incrementaly introduce your existing code, i.e. then put it in a context menu, then localise it etc